# Create JsonObject from @ResponseBody

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dropDown", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
DropDown getList(Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    DropDown dropDown = new DropDown();
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    List<MapTable2> list = contactService.mapProcess();
    for (MapTable2 table : list) {
        Map<String, Object> dataRow = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        dataRow.put("text", table.getProcess());
        dataRow.put("value", table.getId());
        dataRow.put("selected", false);
        dataRow.put("description", table.getProcess());
        dataRow.put("imageSrc", "image.jpg");
        rows.add(dataRow);
    }
    dropDown.setRows(rows);
    return dropDown;
}
```

I need to create following one

```
var ddData = [
{
    text: "Facebook",
    value: 1,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Facebook",
    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
},
{
    text: "Twitter",
    value: 2,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Twitter",
    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
}]
```

I know the issue with my above java coding , I'm not aware to create json array like above.
please check it and help me to correct it.

MapTable2 has ProcessId & ProcessName

```
public class MapTable2 {
private int id;
private String process;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getProcess() {
    return process;
}
public void setProcess(String process) {
    this.process = process;
}
```

}

Comment: Spring's `@ResponseBody` should work fine - you just need to return a `List` of objects with the same field names as the ones in your JSON example. What exactly is the problem you are facing? Your `MapTable2` doesn't seem to bear any relevance to the JSON objects in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Use this [library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). It is very light weight (16KB) and does exactly what you need.
So in your case, you will be using `JSONObject` which internally extends `HashMap`
and do

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
o.put("text","whatever text");
o.put("value",1);
o.put("selected",false);
//and so on
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.add(o);
```

The above will give you this:

```
[
{
text: "Facebook",
value: 1,
selected: false,
description: "Description with Facebook",
imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
}
]
```

To add more objects, add more `JSONObjects` in a loop to `JSONArray`

So as per your given code, just replace `dataRow` with 'JSONObject' and `rows` with `JSONArray` and thats it. In the end, to retrieve the string, do `rows.toString()`.

Comment: thanks. I'm confused with how to iterate that
value: 1, its need to sequentially increase with table.getId()
text: "Facebook",its need to sequentially update with table.getProcess()

Answer (score 3):

@theon is right.

Since you are using `@Responsebody` you can let Spring do the JSON conversion for you. Create a class that matches the objects in the JSON array:

```
public class SomeObject {
    public String getText() { //... }
    public int getValue() { //... }
    public boolean getSelected { // ... }
    public String getDescription { // ... }
    public String getImageSrc { // ... }
}
```

Populate the objects and return it as a list from your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dropDown", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<SomeObject> getList(Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     // Get the objects, return them in a list
}
```

[Add](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or the `@EnableWebMvc` to your application config unless you have not already done so. Make sure that Jackson is available on your classpath and then Spring will automatically serialize your objects to JSON (if the request has `Content-Type: application/json`. Alternatively, the [produces](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces) attribute can be added to the `@RequestMapping` annotation to always return JSON).